# How to ensure that operations and logs are successful?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging

I have an api that add a row to the database table, I want to add a record to the third party log server at the same time, but I can't think of how to guarantee atomicity.

I see some log examples like this.

```
//begin transaction
logger.LogInformation("executing");
//Insert a row to database.
logger.LogInformation("executed");
//commit transaction
```

I will see 'executed' in the log if it fails during commit, this doesn't seem right.

How do I ensure that important operations are recorded?

Comment: try...finally...?

Comment: If I put the 'executed' in the finally block, the data may be inserted successfully but the log fails.